# Should I use Thread here?

Tags: c#

I'm listening to a REST endpoint that streams down lots of data, and my application needs to save all that data to db. The endpoint that I'm listening to will continuously streams down data, only stopping for 10-50ms at random intervals (anywhere between 1s to 15s).

I'm thinking that the stoppage time is my only chance to save the data to my db. My problem is that sometimes there are too much data that the endpoint starts publishing data before I have finished saving to db.

Should I spawn a new fire-and-forget Thread here just to save it?

```
while (ListeningToStream())
{
  // When the stream stop for a "rest", it sends an empty line
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stream))
  {
    myCollection.Add(stream);
  }
  else
  {
    var t = new Thread(() => SaveToDb(myCollection));
    t.Start();
  }
}
```

I've tried using `await SaveToDb(stream)`, but it doesn't go back to listening to the stream, so I'm not sure if I'm using async/await wrong or it does not fit the current situation.

Comment: What kind of app is this, does it run in a web server? How does it work, for example request-response style, like a web app?

Comment: Are you sure that is this calling `SaveToDb` method

Comment: It's a producer consumer problem. You might add jobs to a [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview) and consume from a separate thread.

Comment: @Flydog57 On bird's eye level, it's a n-tier application. The API backend reads from the db, I have a separate BackgroundWorker (the application in my question) that calls my IoT device (itself publishing a REST endpoint that just streams data) and populate the data to the DB.

Comment: @viveknuna Yes, pretty sure it does. This is all just pseudo-code, it works, but I am not sure whether there are a better way of doing this.

Comment: @weichch Wow, there's a name for this type of problem. Thanks! Will take a look at BlockingCollection.